# Save textView position after drag and Drop using com.jmedeisis.draglinearlayout.DragLinearLayout

Tags: java, android

So I was able to have my textViews drag and drop properly. But when I close the application and re-open it doesn't save the position of the new textViews. In a previous application I was able to save data using SharedPreferences but I couldn't quite get it to work in this scenario. Any insight or help would be appreciated!

Thanks,

```
  DragLinearLayout dragDropAndroidLinearLayout = (DragLinearLayout) findViewById(R.id.drag_drop_layout);
    for (int i = 0; i < dragDropAndroidLinearLayout.getChildCount(); i++) {
        View child = dragDropAndroidLinearLayout.getChildAt(i);
        dragDropAndroidLinearLayout.setViewDraggable(child, child);
    }
```

The code I'm using to implement the drag and drop feature. I guess I'm not sure what part in this code would I use to put into the SharedPreferences if that's the way I would even do it.

Answer (score 0, accepted):

```
Try using setTag and getTag

    for(i=0;i<5;i++){
        final View items= View.inflate(this, R.layout.yourItemStyle, null);
        items.setTag(i);
          final TextView text1= (TextView) note.findViewById(R.id.textView1);
          text1.setId(i);
          dragLinearLayout.addDragView(items, text1,i);
          dragLinearLayout.setOnViewSwapListener(new DragLinearLayout.OnViewSwapListener() {
                        @Override
                        public void onSwap(View firstView, int firstPosition,  View secondView, int secondPosition) {
                            int ID= Integer.parseInt(String.valueOf(firstView.getTag()))
                            String strID = String.valueOf(ID);
                            Log.v("ID",strID ); 
                        }

           });
    }
```